# 2 столбца из БД в 1 ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, cursoradaper

Каким образом можно записать данные из 2-х столбцов базы данных в один список? Слева одни данные, справа другие. `SimpleCursorAdapter` служит лишь для представления одного столбца в одном списке. Есть какие нибудь варианты?

Comment: оба ответа помогли, большое спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете указать произвольное количество виджетов и соответствующих им столбцов в БД в конструкторе `SimpleCursorAdapter`, а не один, как вы думаете. Для этого данные виджеты и столбцы помещаются в массив:

```
 SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
        R.layout.item,
        cursor,
        new String[] { DB.column1, DB.column2 },
        new int[] { R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2 },
        0);
```

где:

*R.layout.item* - разметка для айтема;
*cursor* - данные для списка, где содержатся колонки column1 и column2;
*DB.column1, DB.column2* - имена колонок для вывода в курсоре;
*R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2* - ID виджетов в разметке *R.layout.item*, в которые выводить данные из колонок.

Таким же способом можно указать и произвольное количество `ImageView` для вывода изображений.

Смотрите [этот пример](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/111-urok-52-simplecursoradapter-primer-ispolzovanija.html) для подробностей

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы записать данные из 2-х столбцов базы данных в один список:

1) разрабатываете кастомный layout вашей строки, который будет позиционировать например слева одни данные справа другие;

2) реализуете курсор который будет содержать информацию из двух столбцов вашей БД;

3)реализуете сам SimpleCursorAdapter который будет заполнять ваши view, при этом для того, чтобы разместить информацию из курсора в layout делаете такое сопоставление:

```
String[] from = new String[] { DB.COLUMN_TEXT1, DB.COLUMN_TEXT2 };
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.text2 };
```